# Is there any Chinese-English (or vice versa) dictionary API?

Tags: dictionary, translation

Sadly Google shut down the Google Dictionary. Is there any Chinese-English dictionary web app which provides an API for developers? I don't need whole text translation or examples. Just simple word-to-word dictionary.

Or is there a Creative Commons C-E dictionary file that could be downloaded?

Answer (score 5):

There's the free dictionary called [CEDICT](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=cedict), which is CC-BY-SA 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Unihan](http://unicode.org/charts/unihan.html) database. It has online search that you can use with parameter

Example: [http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=国](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E5%9B%BD) will return you a web-page with translation and different pronunciations.

kDefinition - nation, country, nation-state

kMandarin - GUO2

Also the database Unihan.zip can be downloaded from [here](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/).

By the way Google Translate API now available as a [paid service](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/08/paid-version-of-google-translate-api.html)

Comment: UniHan is not a word dictionary, but a sinogram (Chinese character) dictionary. `kDefinition` gives the meanings of singles glyphs, not (compound) words.